# Getting the wrong output while using DIVs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the below output using Div's,

### Output Required

```
Row1
  Views  Checks  Title    users
                 Topics
Row2
  Views  Checks  Title    users
                 Topics
Row3
  Views  Checks  Title    users
                 Topics
```

Below is my code for it,

### HTML

```
   <div class="blockdiv" >
    <div class="views">
        TotalViews
    </div>
    <div class="answers">
        TotalAnswers
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
        title<br>
        Topic
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        UserId
    </div>
</div>

<div  class="blockdiv">
    <div class="views">
        TotalViews
    </div>
    <div class="answers">
        TotalAnswers
    </div>      
    <div class="titles">
        title<br>
        Topic           
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        UserId
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
            .views{
            float:left;
            width:10;
            padding:5px;
        }

        .answers{
            float:left;
            width:10;
            padding:5px;
        }

        .titles{
            float:left;
            width:200;
            padding:5px;
        }

        .user{
            float:left;
            width:40;
            padding:5px;
        }

        #blockdiv{

        float:none;
        clear:all;
        }
```

### Current Output

```
   TotalViews TotalAnswers title   UserId       TotalViews TotalAnswers title    UserId
                           Topic                                        Topic
```

I am getting both of the div side by side.

How to make the second div go to the next line?

Thanks

Comment: `clear:all` is not a possible value, use `clear:both` [Clearing Floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: This is a table data? Use tables to output table data.

Comment: Like @doktorgradus said, tables are not bad when used correctly. They are there for tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

```
.blockdiv { 
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
```

You also may want to add units to all instances of `width`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Chkug/1/

use a div with

```
clear:both
```

between the two divs, this clears the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Your last css rule `#blockdiv` is for an `id`

Change it to

```
.blockdiv{

        float:none;
        clear:both;
        }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6EH3a/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="blockdiv">
```

and you are using `#` in css instead of `.`

```
#blockdiv {   
   float:none;       
   clear:all;  
}
```

Comment: Double check your markup, `'#'blockdiv` should be `#blockdiv`

Comment: hahaha...i was highlighting # in the code using ' ' to visually show where it went wrong...